# Why does the JVM Heap Usage Max as reported by JMX change over time?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

My JVM heap max is configured at 8GB on the name node for one of my hadoop clusters.  When I monitor that JVM using JMX, the reported maximum is constantly fluctuating, as shown in the attached image.

http://highlycaffeinated.com/assets/images/heapmax.png

I only see this behavior on one (the most active) of my hadoop clusters. On the other clusters the reported maximum stays fixed at the configured value.  Any ideas why the reported maximum would change?

**Update:**

The java version is "1.6.0_20"

The heap max value is set in hadoop-env.sh with the following line:

`export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Xmx8G -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004 $JMX_SHARED_PROPS"`

ps shows:

`hadoop   27605     1 99 Jul30 ?        11-07:23:13 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Xmx1000m -Xmx8G`

**Update 2:**

Added the `-Xms8G` switch to the startup command line last night:

`export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Xms8G -Xmx8G -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004 $JMX_SHARED_PROPS"`

As shown in the image below, the max value still varies, although the pattern seems to have changed.

http://highlycaffeinated.com/assets/images/heapmax2.png

**Update 3:**

Here's a new graph that also shows Non-Heap max, which stays constant:

http://highlycaffeinated.com/assets/images/heapmax3.png

Comment: I suspect max is not set on this node. If not set, JVM determines how much to use. What is java version?

Comment: I updated the question with the java version and max settings.  ps shows two values for Xmx - it is this way on all the clusters.  The second value seems to be the one being used.

Comment: Did you try setting Xms to see if it changes anything?

Comment: Haven't tried Xms but I'll give it a shot.  Its a production cluster, so I can't restart very often.

Comment: `-Xmx1000m -Xmx8G`? Where does `-Xmx1000m`come from? Is the same command line as the others?

Comment: @antispam The hadoop startup script uses a variable `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` to set an Xmx value for *all* the hadoop processes on a machine.  On the name node machine, and for the name node process only, I explicitly set Xm8G, in the `HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS`.  This causes the startup script to pass both values to the JVM.  From what I see form JMX, the second value is apparently used since the max starts at 8GB.  What I don't understand is why it fluctuates after that.

Comment: BTW you have 400mb fluctuation, this is totally normal for a namenode.

Comment: But if the maximum is a configured value, why would it ever change?  And why doesn't it change on the name nodes for any of my other clusters?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) documentation, memory usage is reported in two categories, "Heap" and "Non-Heap" memory. The description of the Non-Heap category says:

> The Java virtual machine manages memory other than the heap (referred as non-heap memory).
>   The Java virtual machine has a method area that is shared among all threads. The method area belongs to non-heap memory. It stores per-class structures such as a runtime constant pool, field and method data, and the code for methods and constructors. It is created at the Java virtual machine start-up.
>
> The method area is logically part of the heap but a Java virtual machine implementation may choose not to either garbage collect or compact it. Similar to the heap, the method area may be of a fixed size or may be expanded and shrunk. The memory for the method area does not need to be contiguous.

This description sounds a lot like the permanent generation (PermGen), which is indeed part of the heap and counts against the memory allocated using the `-Xmx` flag. I'm not sure why they decided to report this separately since it is part of the heap.

I suspect that the fluctuations you're seeing are a result of the JVM shrinking and growing the permanent generation, which would cause the reported max heap space available for non-PermGen uses to change accordingly. If you could get a sum of the Heap and Non-Heap maxes as reported by JMX and this sum stays constant at the 8G limit, that would verify this hypothesis.

Comment: I added another graph to show the Non-Heap maximum.  As you can see, it remains constant so I don't think its the PermGen.  Also, I don't see the Heap max vary on any of the other clusters, just this one.

Comment: Oh well, it was a good guess. Other scenarios I can think of: (a) the reported max might be less than your configured value if the JVM can detect that not all of the configured amount is available from the OS, or (b) the heap max is computed as the sum of the maxes for the various GC generations, whose individual maxes might not account for the full 8GB. But that's all conjecture.

Comment: Actually scratch (a), because you started with -Xms which should request the full 8GB from the OS on start-up.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the JVM survivor space is fluctuating in max-size.

The JVM max-size reported by JMX via the HeapMemoryUsage.max attribute is not the actual max-size of the heap (i.e. the one set with -Xmx )

The reported value is the max heap size minus the max survivor space size

To get the total max heap size, add the two jmx attributes:

```
java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage.max + java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Survivor Space/Usage.max
```

(tested on oracle jdk 1.7.0_45)