# MemoryUsage max changing over time

Tags: java, memory

I'm writing some monitoring code, to keep track of used memory within my application. I've found the MemoryMXBean which allows me to investigate the memory usage. But I can't get really hold on the max value, from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html):

> **max**: represents the maximum amount of memory (in bytes) that can be used for memory management. Its value may be undefined. The maximum amount of memory may change over time if defined.

Under which circumstances can the max value be null? I thought it would be always set, even if I didn't set it explicit on startup. And how can the max value change over time if I set it? There's some related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905220/why-does-the-jvm-heap-usage-max-as-reported-by-jmx-change-over-time), but no answer to the problem.

Can someone bring light into the dark?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure when max memory usage can be null but I can tell how it changes over time. The max value represents the maximum memory ever used by your program in it's lifetime, capped by the `Xmx` JVM argument.

So when your program starts (with `Xmx` say 1g), the max may be 256m. As the program runs and requires more memory, JVM will provision more memory for it and the max will increase, say to 512m. Now the program is done processing and the memory required falls, GC kicks in and reclaims the memory. But the max stays at 512m.

The max will never go above what is specified by the `Xmx` argument. If it hits the limit (1g in this case), they it will stay at that value till the end of the run of your program.

Comment: Hm, I doubt this. Where did you get this information from, can you point me to it? Your explanation wouldn't match to the before mentioned thread, which has decreases in the max value for heap. Do you refer to MemoryPoolMXBean, which has a Peak Information?